# Neural network output(y_predict) sticks together, what might be the reason?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

y_predict is expected to be in range of [0, 1], but my y_predict is in a small range: [0.16124, 0.16125].

But it somehow worked a little bit, i.e., having an AUC of about 0.7 on both train and test data.

What might be the reason? model capacity? epochs? activation(I used relu and sigmoid)? Appreciate for any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason: some parameters are sooooooooo large that they overwhelmed others. So output becomes similiar after sigmoid.

Solution is l2 regulization. It worked for me.